# awk rounding error using int() in connection with log()

Tags: linux, awk, numeric-data

For later formatting I need to calculate the logarithm, base 10. Fine so far:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { print log(1000) / log(10) }'
3
$ awk 'BEGIN { print log(1001) / log(10) }'
3.00043
```

I need to kick the decimals, so I use `int()`:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { print int(log(1001) / log(10)) }'
3
```

Fine so far. But what's this(!):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { print int(log(1000) / log(10)) }'
2
```

Can anyone explain this rounding error or whatever this should be?

And what's the correct approach to solve the problem?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: try `awk 'BEGIN { printf "%.17g\n", log(1000) / log(10) }'` and you'll see why.

Comment: Okay ... So what's the correct approach?

Comment: There's no "correct" way to use binary floats as if they were decimal. But you can try rounding it: `int(log(1000) / log(10) + .5)`

Comment: Thanks - that will do the trick for me!

Comment: @mosvy Of course there is a "correct way" to use floats: as they were designed to work.

Answer (score 0):

Rounding is never easy, nor could it it be **exact**, however, up to 15 digits (for a 53 bit mantissa) the approximation (rounding) should happen toward the correct number.

```
$ printf '%s\n' 999 1000 1001 | awk '{ v=log($1) / log(10); printf("%.15g\n",v) }'
2.99956548822598
3
3.00043407747932
```

So, rounding  to the nearest integer (toward zero, also correct for negative numbers) with `%i` will give the integer you need:

```
$ printf '%s\n' 999 1000 1001 | 
    awk '{ 
           v=log($1) / log(10); 
           result=sprintf("%.15g",v); 
           printf("%-15s %i\n",v, result)
         }
        '
2.99957         2
3               3
3.00043         3
```

This should work correctly up to 14 digit numbers (don't try to expand beyond that with the default 53 bit mantissa of awk, it will fail in some cases).